# Why isn't Java's nio.ByteBuffer serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

Sometimes it would make sense to serialize it across with rest of data. Right now we have to unwrap it.

Edit: is there some other option available? E.g. Apache commons lang has MutableInt which is lightweight wrapper around primitive int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that since the contents of a ByteBuffer are already a blob, and so reading/writing them to/from streams/channels is not a complicated matter the designers of the language saw no need to make ByteBuffers serializable.

You could in theory make your own Externalizable ByteBuffer impl, something like:

```
package java.nio; //has to be in java.nio pkg, _get() and _put and pkg-private

public class SerializableByteBuffer extends ByteBuffer implements Externalizable {
    private ByteBuffer theActualBuffer;

    public SerializableByteBuffer(ByteBuffer theActualBuffer) {
        super(0, 0, 1, 1);
        this.theActualBuffer = theActualBuffer;
    }

    // these 2 are package private. this was obviously not designed to be extended

    @Override
    byte _get(int i) {
        return theActualBuffer._get(i);
    }

    @Override
    void _put(int i, byte b) {
        theActualBuffer._put(i, b);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        //write length + type of underlying buffer (enum?) + contents
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //read length and type of buffer, instantiate buffer of correct type, read contents into buffer
    }

    //delegate all methods. this is going to be a lot of work as some return buffer copies
}
```

but given that you'd have to place it in the java.nio package, and correctly delegate ~20 methods (some of which are tricky) it'll be a lot of hard work and the results will never be pretty.

also, the actual (de)serialization will never be truly efficient as there's no way (that i know of?) to get a `Channel` from an `ObjectOutput`, which means you'll need to do it the old fashioned way with an intermediate byte[4096] buffer or something

Comment: We tried something like that but find it to be a double wrapper of an array of bytes. Seems bad if we have 3-4 byte buffer fields in millions of rows. What do you think?

Comment: @Dragonborn - depends on what youre after. if its performance i wouldnt use built-in serialization at all and go with something faster (kryo? avro? protobuf? bson? flat-buffers?). if its any other consideration (readability of the payload, cross-version compatibility, cross-language compatibility) i'd go with xml/json. basically the only thing built-in serialization has going for it is ease of use for (very) small setups with very basic requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I answered in the next post with an example for custom serialization:
[How to serialize ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982704/how-to-serialize-bytebuffer/33520115#33520115)

Basically the point is that ByteBuffer is a wrapper for byte arrays so it has no sense to serialize it (instead you should serialize the byte[]).
Just in case you need to serialize a ByteBuffer then... do something like

```
public class NetByteBuffer implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2831273345165209113L;

    //serializable property
    String anotherProperty;

    // mark as transient so this is not serialized by default
    transient ByteBuffer data;

    public NetByteBuffer(String anotherProperty, ByteBuffer data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.anotherProperty = anotherProperty;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        // write default properties
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        // write buffer capacity and data
        out.writeInt(data.capacity());
        out.write(data.array());

    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //read default properties
        in.defaultReadObject();

        //read buffer data and wrap with ByteBuffer
        int bufferSize = in.readInt();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        this.data = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    public String getAnotherProperty() {
        return anotherProperty;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it really matter why? Although there's definitely a potential issue when direct buffers are used.

If you need to do this just occasionally, you can write your own `writeObject()`/`readObject()` implementations for handling the serialization.